Is semantic security equvalent to IND-CPA?
Is semantic security equivalent to IND-CPA?
If a PKE scheme like ElGamal is semantically secure, can we say it is IND-CPA?
What's the relationship between semantic security and IND-CPA?

TL;DR: In my understanding a scheme is semantically secure under a specific attack scenario. Commonly when semantic security is mentioned without indicating the scenario then it probably comes down to IND-CPA, but I'd check the context. You might say that semantic security covers the IND part of IND-XXX :P Not posting this as an answer, as I hope that a more canonical answer is possible.

Interestingly, I couldn't find a dupe of this basic question, that closes is this Why is "semantically secure" important for cryptosystems?. It is so basic that almost all modern books cover this.

Semantic security is equivalent to IND-CPA security for public key encryption (PKE), as mentioned in @Mahesh S R's answer. But in more advanced forms of PKE, like functional encryption, these concepts of security are NOT equal. Semantic security for FE is stronger than IND-CPA security IACR 2010/556 and IACR 2010/543.

Goldwasser and Micali showed that semantic security-CPA and IND-CPA and equivalent. In-fact Watanabe et al. (see figure 1) showed that semantic security and indistinguishability are equivalent under any form of attack.
